# How do you unpivot GA4 (Google Analytics 4) event_params (JSON) in SQL Server?

Tags: json, sql-server, google-analytics, google-analytics-4

We are exporting GA4 (Google Analytics 4) data from Big Query via a built-in Microsoft connector.  Everything is coming through, but the event_params is in a very unusual JSON format.  I have unpivoted numerous other arrays from different sources with no issue using the OPENJSON function and CROSS APPLY but this one is beating me so far.

I have searched around the internet and so far I have only found documentation on how to do it in Big Query, which doesn't work for me with the built in connectors.

My goal is to pivot each of the params and values with non-null values into their own columns, such as below, although there are about 10 custom columns I will have in the end.

| event_date | event_timestamp | page_location | ga_session number | etc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| First | row |  |  |  |
| Second | row |  |  |  |

Below is a sample of my data

| event_date | event_timestamp | event_params |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20221022 | 1666490454564810 | {"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"page_location"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"https://welcome.mypage.com/"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"ga_session_number"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"page_title"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"Welcome Hub"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"engaged_session_event"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"ga_session_id"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1666490454"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"ignore_referrer"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"page_referrer"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"https://login.mypage.com/callback?code=rgE7OZ3rLlJb8NcqfzOF370PhKojttNbKOddEKxg3p2aL&state=RDlGdC1vQWRlR0VHTHQ3M1p3TlVvS0hnVTVSbXA4UVM0NGtNR2ljbkl1Vg%3D%3D"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}}]} |
| 20221022 | 1666490454564810 | {"v":[{"v":{"f":[{"v":"engaged_session_event"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"page_referrer"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"https://login.mypage.com/callback?code=rgE7OZ3rLlJb8NcqfzOF370PhKojttNbKOddEKxg3p2aL&state=RDlGdC1vQWRlR0VHTHQ3M1p3TlVvS0hnVTVSbXA4UVM0NGtNR2ljbkl1Vg%3D%3D"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"ignore_referrer"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"true"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"page_title"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"Welcome Hub"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"ga_session_number"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"ga_session_id"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1666490454"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"session_engaged"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":null},{"v":"1"},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"page_location"},{"v":{"f":[{"v":"https://welcome.mypage.com/"},{"v":null},{"v":null},{"v":null}]}}]}}]} |

Answer (score 0):

i have the same problem than you for the GA4 data.

After searching, i found that you can select the column and on the transformation tab clic on analyse JSON. After it's possible to expand the column.

But when expanding the column, it's not helping that much to have header column with event... :/

Answer (score 0):

My solution (which I don't like) is to use the query option of the Big Query connector and bring every event as a json into my sql db... then parse the data either using JSON_QUERY or maybe ADF data flow.

At least this way it keeps all the names correctly... but there's more manual work with the jsons...

```
SELECT TO_JSON_STRING(t) as value from   
   `BigQueryTable.events_*` as t
WHERE
   _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20221127' AND '20221128'
```